# Notation for a sum with restricted set of indices

Tags: notation

I have the following sum where $i$ goes, one at a time from 1 to $n$: $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{a_i}$

But what is the notation for summation with the condition that $i$ should still go from 1 to 10 but $i$ must not take some value $j$. So for example if $j = 4$, $i$ would take on the values 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: I do not think there is a common rule for this. I would prefer in such a case the notation $$\sum_{1\le i \le n}^{i\ne j}a_i.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\limits_{i = 1 \\ i \ne j}^n a_i$

Comment: Then what if j is 1?

Comment: if $j = 1$ you may write $\sum\limits_{i = 2}^2 a_i$.

if $j = 4$ you may write $\sum\limits_{i = 1 \\ i \ne 4}^2 a_i$.